Unreal Engine Metahuman Rigging (Blender Rig)
Overview: Important information: Using Blender 4.0, (Blender Help Subreddit took my post down within the minute cause they can't read context), this is more of questions with a goal.
I've been trying to find an animation solution for Unreal Engine's Metahuman for a while now, it infuriates me that Maya gets a rig up front, and since I'm basically poor, Blender is my only animation program I have access to, and the fact that it gets straight up ignored has me infuriated. I've spent months looking for anything, and with all the results being either dead-ends or cop-outs, I decided the most efficient way for me to do it is just to create a rig in Blender. My ultimate goal for this rig is to be able to animate the Unreal Engine Metahuman in Blender to take advantage of action strips and other features to create animation montages and cutscenes. I've seen a ton of posts that just stop out of nowhere and conclude that it's not possible for no reason, so, this is my final solution for anybody that's found themselves in the same position I've been in for the past 2 years, when I'm finished with the rig I'm gonna release it for free on Gumroad or somewhere similar. That, and I'll make a simple tutorial on how to switch the meshes, please label responses to questions and feel free to ask more questions and provide feedback and thoughts.

Questions:
#1.   IK workaround
The bones provided in the skeleton are parented, but detached. Is there a way to get IK working with the skeleton like this? I've tried to use the IK constraint on the hand, but it's very weird. It works perfectly without any target or pole data, but the constraint is obviously invalid without that information, additionally, when I move the hand bone it doesn't save the world position leaving me unable to Alt+G the bone or animate it (Rotation is unaffected). What's a good way to achieve IK from the Hand to the Clavicle like my example without it breaking?


#2.   Twist Bones
I understand how twist bones work, but don't know to to drive the rotation of the twists with the rotation of another bone (Ex. Turning the hand twists the forearm.). Specifically the arm, when the hand comes up, the bicep twists outward. If I can't drive it, I'll just make a control for it.

#3.   Slide Bones ~
What is a slide bone, I assume it slides along an axis similar to a twist? Could I get any sources on this topic?
The main problem I'm encountering is how to implement these into a coherent rig, thank you for responses.
